# ¿Cómo llamar una función que obtiene los valores de una tabla, al quitar un checkbox que se encuentra en otra tabla?

Tags: jquery

Visualmente tengo estas dos tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pretendo hacer es que al momento de quitar el check que se encuentra en la tabla "Préstamos de crédito asignados a tu código" llamar a la siguiente función:

```
$$('.formas_pagos_seleccionados').on('click', '.eliminarformaPago', function() {
    console.log("Eliminar forma de pago");
    let forma_pago = $(this).closest('tr');
    let fecha_prestamo = forma_pago.find('.fecha_prestamo').text();
    let numero_documento = forma_pago.find('.nombre_forma_pago').text();
    let cod_cliente = forma_pago.find('.cod_cliente').text();
    let monto = parseFloat(forma_pago.find('.monto').text().replace(/,/, '')) || 0;
    let nombre_forma_pago = forma_pago.find('.nombre_forma_pago').text();
    let cod_banco;
    console.log(numero_documento);

    $(".prestamos_creditos").find(".prestamo[attr-num-doc='" + numero_documento + "']").prop('checked', false);
    $(".formas_pagos").find(".tipo_pago[attr-num-doc='" + nombre_forma_pago + "']").prop('checked', false);
    $(".formas_pagos").find(".cantidad[attr-num-doc='" + nombre_forma_pago + "']").prop('disabled', false).val("");
    $(".formas_pagos").find(".tipo_pago[attr-num-doc='" + nombre_forma_pago + "']").prop('disabled', false);
    cod_forma_pago_seleccionadoAnterior = "";

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    console.log("ESTE ES EL MONTO QUE SE ELIMINO: " + monto);
    sumatoria_saldo_favor = sumatoria_saldo_favor - monto;


    saldo_pendiente_cancelar += monto;
    console.log("SALDO PENDIENTE: " + saldo_pendiente_cancelar);
    //saldo_pendiente_cancelar = total_pagar-monto_favor;
    $('.saldo_pendiente').text(moneda(saldo_pendiente_cancelar));
    monto_favor -= monto;
    console.log("VARIABLE MONTO A FAVOR: " + monto_favor);
    var cod_forma_pago = 11;
    eliminarformaPago(idPedido, cod_forma_pago, monto, cod_banco, fecha_prestamo, numero_documento, cod_cliente);
    console.log("DE ESTE VALOR QUEDO SUMATORIA SALDO FAVOR: " + sumatoria_saldo_favor);
});
```

Ya que dicha función anterior escrita me sirve para obtener los valores de la tabla "Formas de pago seleccionadas".

Entonces cuando yo selecciono un check de la tabla "Préstamos de crédito asignados a tu código" ejecuto esta funcion:

```
$$('#prestamos_creditos').on('click', '.prestamo', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Obtengo el valor al estar chequeado
    } else {
        // Quiero mandar a llamar la función antes descrita, para obtener
        // los valores de la tabla "Formas de pago seleccionadas"
    }
});
```

Comment: Deberias tener un id que relacione las dos tablas y agregar / eliminar basado en ese id.

Answer (score 0):

Hice un ejemplo basándome en lo que necesitas, lo que tienes que hacer es asignarle un identificador a las filas(tr) de ambas tablas:

Tengo 2 tablas, una tiene un checkbox, y ese row tiene un id="row1" y en la otra tabla, tengo otro row con ese mismo id(este id sería reemplazado por un identificador tuyo en tu bd)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $( "#prestamos_creditos" ).click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Obtengo el valor al estar chequeado
    } else {
        // Quiero mandar a llamar la función antes descrita, para obtener
        // los valores de la tabla "Formas de pago seleccionadas"
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var idAttr = tr.attr("id");
  tr.remove();
  otraTabla(idAttr);
 
    }
 });
  function otraTabla(idRow) {
   $("#test2 tr#"+idRow+"").remove();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test1">
<thead>
  <th>test1</th>
</thead>
<tr id="row1">
  <td><input id="prestamos_creditos" type="checkbox" /> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="test2">
<thead>
  <th>test1</th>
</thead>
<tr id="row1">
  <td>Hola</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Espero y te sirva. Saludos.